# How to stop printing 243?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, pow

This is a C program snippet designed to find the first power of 3 which are less than 100. It keeps printing  243.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{

    int product = 3;

    while ( product <= 100 )
    {
        product = 3 * product;
    
        printf ("%d\n" , product);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove this line `printf ("%d\n" , product);` is will no longer print ;) But seriously, you print before you do the check. You can swap the lines on the loop.

Comment: By first power of 3 < 100, do you mean it should print 3, 9, 27, 81?

Comment: Now seems like a good time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement to see what really happens in your program.

Comment: Swap the two lines inside the `while` loop.

Comment: yes i forgot the 3 as well

Comment: It prints 243 because the previous value is 81, so the loop is executed another time at which points it becomes 243, which is printed, before you check if it is < 100.

Comment: @ianAbbot It worked . Thanks.

Comment: you should really [learn how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) because you'll have to use it until the end of your coding life

Answer (score 2):

You are multiplying `product` with `3` before printing it. Due to this, a value which is more than 100 gets printed. If you swap the lines in loop and print first and multiply from `3` after that; `product` will not enter in while loop during it's fourth iteration

```c
while ( product <= 100 )
{
    printf ("%d\n" , product);
    product = 3 * product;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you are checking the current value of the variable `product` and if it satisfies the condition you multiply it by `3`. So as a result you will get a value that is greater than `100`.

You should check whether the multiplication of the current value of `product` by `3` is less than `100` and if so do the multiplication.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int Base = 3;
    const int UpperBound = 100;
    
    int product = 1;
    
    while ( product * Base < UpperBound )
    {
        product *= Base;
    }
    
    printf( "%d\n", product );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
81
```

If you need to output all powers of 3 that are less than 100 then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int Base = 3;
    const int UpperBound = 100;
    
    for ( int product = 1; product < UpperBound; product *= Base )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", product );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
3
9
27
81
```

`1` corresponds to `3 ^ 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The greatest power of `3` which is less than `100` is `4`. Your code prints up to power `5` which is `243`. To understand the problem, you need to understand the flow of the `while` loop. Its psuedo-code can be:

1. `product` = suppose `81` from previous executions.
2. Enter `while` loop
3. Change value of product
4. Print value of product

So in this flow, your code changes value of `product` and then prints it so obviously the changed value resulting `243` will be printed.

To solve this, print the value of `product` before changing it. So your final code would be as follows:

```
while ( product <= 100 )
{
    printf ("%d\n" , product);

    product = 3 * product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Print before multiplying**

```
#define LIMIT 100
while ( product <= LIMIT ) {
    printf ("%d\n" , product); // Move here.
    product = 3 * product;
    // printf ("%d\n" , product);
}
```

**But let us go deeper**

What if the limit was `INT_MAX` and not 100?  `3 * product;` would incur signed integer overflow, which is *undefined behavior*, UB.  A likely outcome is the loop will never stop as `product <= INT_MAX` is always true.  A better approach is to detect that potential overflow.

```
#define LIMIT 100 /* Or any int value */
while ( product <= LIMIT/3 ) {
    product = 3 * product;
    printf ("%d\n" , product);
}
```